# R DataTable Count Values In Column

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)
data=data.table("cat"=c(0,5,NA,0,0,0),
                "fox"=c(2,0,NA,NA,7,0))

data[, Count0 := cat + fox]
data$WANT = c(1,1,NA,1,1,2)
```

I wash to count 0 values in 'cat' and fox' and my attempt shown is 'Count0' but desired output is 'WANT'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
data=data.table("cat"=c(0,5,NA,0,0,0),
                "fox"=c(2,0,NA,NA,7,0))

cols <- c("cat","fox")
data[,count0:=rowSums(data[,.SD,.SDcols=cols]==0,na.rm = TRUE)]
data[rowMeans(is.na(data[,..cols]))==1,count0:=NA_integer_]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks so much but i wish to name the columns by name and not use 'data==0' because i have other columns in my data too

Comment: @bvowe you can do `data[,Count0:=rowSums(data[,.SD,.SDcols = "your col names"]==0,na.rm = TRUE)]` then

Comment: that is perfect thank you so much. what if i wish to replace values in 'cat' and 'fox'  that equal to 0 or 2 with -99? I wish to name 'cat' and 'fox' by name but not the column number? last question!!!

Comment: `dt[fox == 0, fox := -99]`

Comment: @frank zhang; i notice if cat and fox are both NA then Count0 equals to 0 but it should equal to NA

Comment: @bvowe hey I update the answer and show you two ways to call your column names.

Comment: @frank zhang that's great so great!

Answer (score 0):

We can use :

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("cat","fox")

data[,ans := rowSums(.SD == 0, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = cols]
data[ans == 0, ans := NA]
data

#   cat fox and
#1:   0   2   1
#2:   5   0   1
#3:  NA  NA  NA
#4:   0  NA   1
#5:   0   7   1
#6:   0   0   2
```